# AZ mapping per user

Tags: amazon-web-services, availability-zone, aws-regions

I read "Each AWS Account has independently mapped AZs, which can vary between different accounts" in a book.
As far as I know , each region has its well-defined AZs.
So how does it come that the AZs vary from a user to another ?

Comment: Most likely to prevent unbalanced use of any one AZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Availability Zone A for my AWS account may not be the same as Availability Zone A for your account. The AZ mappings are created when your account is generated.

The idea is to distribute customer workloads within a region. Most customers pick AZs A, B, or C when launching instances (human nature). If everyone had the same AZ A, workloads would be hugely unbalanced in a region, and that AZ would be a failure point for a lot of customers.

Comment: Just to add a clarification: AZ assignment is based on **Accounts**. Within an account, all IAM Users will experience the same AZs. However, AZs may differ *between* different AWS Accounts.